# Microsoft Edge WebView2 - Error: The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I'm working on this official tutorial: [Getting started with WebView2 in WPF (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf).

1. Have installed `Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Canary channel` on my `Windows 10 pro -ver 1903`.
2. Have created a `.NET Core 3.1 - WPF` project on latest version `VS2019 - ver16.6.3`.
3. Have installed the Nuget package  [Microsoft.Web.WebView2 -Version 0.9.538](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2).

But, per instructions in [step 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf#step-3---create-a-single-webview-in-mainwindowxaml) of the tutorial, when I add namespace `xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"` in `<Window/>` tag of `MainWindow.xaml`, and build (F5) the app, I get the following error at line `using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;` of the `MainWindow.g.cs` file:

**Error**:

> > Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWebView2TEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Question**: What may be a cause of the error and how can it be resoled?

Comment: I have the same issue. The MS guide is not match the actual `WebView2` in WPF. One of suggestions i found is _use preview build instead of release_ but i didn't find a way to install it. Thus i've falled back to the obsolete 1st `WebView` which is using default Edge shipped with Win10 (not Canary).

Comment: I suggest to replace `chromium-embedded` tag with `.net-core` because this question is not about CEF.

Comment: You must install the 'pre-release' version of WebView2 to use it in .Net !

Comment: @PoulBak Your suggestion worked (thank you). For the benefit of other readers, you may want to make your comment a `Response` (giving a brief description noting that the bullet 3 of step 2 of the tutorial also ask for installing prerelease package version and I may have overlooked that instruction and instead installed the newer version of the package). And, I'll mark your response as an `Answer.

Comment: As a side note there is a current thread on this issue in the Github for this error. I recommend watching the page to see when the issue gets closed out: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues/729 and we can start using the release version.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To use the `WebView2` control in `.Net` you must use the the version, that is marked '**pre-release**'.

Only that version contains the .Net librarys necessary.

It is actually mentioned (but not very clear) on the installation page.

When installing, make sure you have 'Include prerelease' checked:
[image]

**Note**: After you have installed the 'pre-release' version, `Visual Studio` will tell you there's an update (which is the version without 'pre-release'). **DO NOT UPGRADE!**

Well, at some point in the future, they will of course support .Net from the standard version, but not for now.

Answer (score 2):

Target framework needs to be 4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

It's System.Web in 2019.

However, if you are trying to get to WebView Class, you need to use the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namspace.

I can read your code and see what your trying to do and this is what is it is fro Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your posts, especially ones containing links back to your own content.  Stack Overflow is all about content—it's not a traditional discussion forum.  Feel free to add any information you'd normally have in your signature to your profile.  If people like your content, they might click through to find out more about you.