# set UserAgent in Webview2

Tags: user-agent, webview2

i am creating a desktop application with Webview2 as browser. I have to change the user agent to get data from a website.  My control name is Webview21 for the browser control. I got the error message System.NotImplementedException: 'Unable to cast to Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.Raw.ICoreWebView2Settings2.
This may happen if you are using an interface not supported by the version of the WebView2 Runtime . But i have the latest evergreen version.
What is the solution?

```
 Public Async Sub InitializeBrowser()
    Dim strip As String = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Edg/90.0.818.62 seakayak-navigator"

    Dim opts As New CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions With {.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access "}




    Dim userDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\SeakayakNavigator"
    Dim env = Await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(Nothing, userDataFolder)
    Await WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)
    Application.DoEvents()

    WebView21.Width = Fmenu.Width
    WebView21.Height = Fmenu.Height
    WebView21.Top = 0
    WebView21.Left = 0
    WebView21.BringToFront()
    WebView21.CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent = strip

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.


    AddHandler WebView21.NavigationCompleted, AddressOf webview21_navigationCompleted
    WebView21.CoreWebView2.AddHostObjectToScript("Bridge", New Bridge())




End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent`is not supported in the current **stable** release (version 1.0.818.41).
If you want to use `CoreWebView2.Settings.UserAgent` you must install the **pre-release** version, currently version 1.0.865-prerelease.

You can follow the directions here: [To install a pre-release version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62845448/microsoft-edge-webview2-error-the-type-or-namespace-name-web-does-not-exist/62854942#62854942)

That also means that you must use Microsoft Edge **CANARY** build
which you can get here: [Microsoft Edge Insider Channels](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download)

Unfortunately, you might have to uninstall the 'WebView2 runtime' (which I think is a bug in the WebView2 package).

**Update:**

Now the latest stable version supports setting the
`useragent`.

Comment: thanx this was the solution

Comment: I tried the latest version then I got:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.CoreWebView2.get returned Nothing.

Comment: @frozenade, `WebView2` must be initialized (search for it), that's not related to this question.